# Return data type

Tags: c#, database, silverlight, wcf, service

Can anyone help me identify the return data type is this set of codes???

```
[OperationContract]
        public List<PrimaryClass> getPrimaryList()
        {
            string priConn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SchoolConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            var priList = new List<PrimaryClass>();
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(priConn))
            {
                const string sql = @"SELECT PrimarySchool,TopHonour,Cca,TopStudent,TopAggregate,TopImage FROM [Primary]";
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
                {
                    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(
                        CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                    if (dr != null)
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            var pri = new PrimaryClass
                            {
                                PrimarySchool = dr.GetString(0),
                                TopHonour = dr.GetString(1),
                                Cca = dr.GetString(2),
                                TopStudent = dr.GetString(3),
                                TopAggregate = dr.GetString(4),
                                TopImage = dr.GetString(5)
                            };
                            priList.Add(pri);
                        }
                    return priList;

                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Please be more specific. What are you asking for? Everyone can see the return type of the method is `List<PrimaryClass>` and I doubt *you* can't.

Comment: oic bcuz some1 else was asking me the question and i don't know what to tell him, sorry i'm not really a programmer =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns a `List<>` of `PrimaryClass` classes, setting the `PrimarySchool`, `TopHonour`, `Cca`, `TopStudent`, `TopAggregate`, `TopImage` properties on each one.

Comment: @Craig Tan - No. The return type is a list of `PrimaryClass` instances. Each instance of `PrimaryClass` has the following properties/fields: `PrimarySchool`, `TopHonor`,`Cca`,`TopStudent`,`TopAggregate`,`TopImage`.

Comment: @Thomas yea it juz hit me thanks